# Call to undefined function in Laravel Relationship Query

Tags: php, laravel

As I'll have many search filters I'm building them the way that is shown below. I've shown one filter (for posts) as that's the one that's throwing an error.

**User Model**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Post', 'postable');
}
```

**User Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function searchPage(Request $request, User $user)
    {

        $user = $user->newQuery();

        if ($request->has('post'))
            $user->posts()->where('id', $request->input('post'));

        return $user->get();

    }

}
```

I get: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::posts()` while I thought that this is how it should be done according to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

Comment: If you're already passing `User $user`, you don't need to do `$user = $user->newQuery()` at all; `$user->posts()->where(...);` should work fine on it's own.

Answer (score 2):

`newQuery()` will return an instance of the Query Builder. You cannot chain relationships on that.

```
public function searchPage(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // newQuery returns an instance of Query Builder
    // You can't chain relationships on the Query Builder
    $user = $user->newQuery();

    // You want an instance of the User model here. 
    // This is just an example
    $user = \App\User::find($request->id); 

    // If you are already passing in the user model
    // you can just use it as it is. No need to do 

    if ($request->has('post')) {
        $user->posts()->where('id', $request->input('post'));
    }

    return $user->get();
}
```

Comment: I think I'm confused here. From the docs: "Since Eloquent models are query builders, you should review all of the methods available on the query builder. You may use any of these methods in your Eloquent queries." Can I do `$user = \App\User::all();` and then apply conditional where clauses to it later like `$user->where('status', 'active')`?

Comment: Yes, but relationship definitions are in your models.

Comment: If I start with `$users = User::where('status', 'active')` (which is Eloquent, correct?) instead of `newQuery()` and then do `$user->posts()->where` etc.. it doesn't work.

Comment: `User::where('status', 'active')` would return an instance of Query Builder which won't work. `User::where('status', 'active')->first();` will work as that will be an instance of `App\User`. I hope you get my point :)

Comment: OK thanks. I now see that I need to make sure that I get an Eloquent instance. As I want to start with all users, and then apply where filters later, how do I do this? I've tried `$users = User::all()` (as per the docs) and then apply `$users->posts()` which doesn't work.

Comment: I ended up using `$users = User::query()` and to query the relationship `$users->whereHas('posts', function ($query) use ($post_id) {
       $query->where('id', $post_id);
   });`